# Remove and Update json object using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json array with objects. Each object has bunch of key and values. Using `ng-repeat` to shown the object's in my html page. If i click edit for the particular object, an object will toggle on `bootstrap` modal. If changes made in the modal window, its directly affects the `json` object and instant changes should occur in UI. so i using a `angular.copy` to take an duplicate object and shown in the modal window. I want to do, if i click **update** button means within the modal dialog, splice the json object and insert the `duplicated` json object into the array within the same index. How can i do it. Here sample code

```
   $scope.array = [{"ItemId":"20113",
                   "ItemModel":"C2",
                   "ItemName":"Nokia", .....},
                   {....}, 
                   {....},
                   {....}, ......]
```

I want `splice` index 2 in the array and insert an new object in the array as the same index of 2

Comment: Please post code that shows how you are using ng-repeat and other things to show data in modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Why are you using angular.copy?</s>

If you were passing the object you want to edit, you wouldn't need to refres it afterwards. (sorry I misread that you needed an update button)

Although, to answer your question, your solution would be to replace the object by the new one :

```
$scope.array[index] = modifiedObject;
```